# Substitute one equation into another in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I have equations `x = z + 2` and `y = x + 1` and I wish to substitute the first one into the second one, to eliminate `x` and get `y = z + 3`. In SymPy, I can create the first two equations as:

```python
x = sympy.symbols('x')
y = sympy.symbols('y')
z = sympy.symbols('z')
equation_one = sympy.Eq(x, z + 2)
equation_two = sympy.Eq(y, x + 1)
```

What is the correct way to now substitute `equation_one` into `equation_two`? The output should be a new equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach that works in this case is to use the attributes lhs/rhs ("left hand side" and "right hand side").

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')
y = sp.symbols('y')
z = sp.symbols('z')
equation_one = sp.Eq(x, z + 2)
equation_two = sp.Eq(y, x + 1)

print(equation_two.subs(equation_one.lhs,equation_one.rhs))
```

Result:

```
Eq(y, z + 3)
```